# How to search using barba.js in wordpress

Tags: javascript

I am currently using barba.js to create a wordpress theme, but I have no idea how to make it work with the search feature.

If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

The current code is as follows:

```
// Rewrite in head
const replaceHead = function(data){
    const head = document.head;
    const newPageRawHead = data.next.html.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0];
    const newPageHead = document.createElement('head');
    newPageHead.innerHTML = newPageRawHead;

    const removeHeadTags = [ 
        "meta[name='keywords']"
        ,"meta[name='description']"
        ,"meta[property^='og']"
        ,"meta[name^='twitter']"
        ,"meta[itemprop]"
        ,"link[itemprop]"
        ,"link[rel='prev']"
        ,"link[rel='next']"
        ,"link[rel='canonical']"
    ].join(',');
    
    const headTags = head.querySelectorAll(removeHeadTags)

    for (let i = 0; i < headTags.length; i++) {
        head.removeChild(headTags[i]);
    }
    
    const newHeadTags = newPageHead.querySelectorAll(removeHeadTags)

    for (let i = 0; i < newHeadTags.length; i++) {
        head.appendChild(newHeadTags[i]);
    }
}

barba.hooks.beforeEnter((data) => {
    replaceHead(data);
})

barba.init({
    transitions: [{}]
});
```

I found the code to make Contact Form 7 work and thought I could divert it, but gave up because I didn't know how to do it.

```
barba.init({
    transitions: [{
      beforeEnter({ next }) {
        wpSearchFromRun(next);
      }
    }]
});

function wpSearchFromRun(next) {
    var wpSearchForm = '.search-form';
    var wpForm = $(next.container).find(wpSearchForm);
    if (wpForm.length) {
      $(wpSearchForm).each(function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        //n.init( $form[0] );
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const form = document.getElementById("searchform");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   let formData = new FormData(form);
   let search = new URLSearchParams(formData);
   let queryString = search.toString();

   barba.go(`?${queryString}`);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).